# Портировать код Perl -> Python

Tags: python, perl

Дали задание. Перевести perl код в python и я что-то аналогов в питоне найти не могу. Не могли бы объяснить как портировать данный код в python.

```
sub ver {
  my ($app) = @_;

  if(!$app->{app_version}) {
      my $svnversion = qx(svnversion -n);
      if(!$svnversion || $svnversion =~ m{^\D}xms) {
          $svnversion = q(197SA);
      }
       $app->{app_version} = qq(DB Loader 2.0.$svnversion);
  }
  return $app->{app_version};
}
```

Comment: подобные вопросы, если не указать какая именно конструкция вызывает у вас затруднения не слишком полезны. То есть можно спросить, к примеру, «Как `qx(svnversion -n)` из Перла на Питон перенести». Ещё лучше просто спросить: «Как выполнить внешнюю команду на Питоне аналогичную примеру на Перле: `qx(svnversion -n)`» или если вы не знаете, что `qx(svnversion -n)` делает, то сперва об этом спросить.

Answer (score 0):

Так дали Вам задание или нам:)?

```
def ver(app):
  if not app['app_version']:
    svnversion = `svnversion -n`
    if len(svnversion) == 0 or <первый символ svnversion  не цифра>:
      svnversion = '197SA'
    app['app_version'] = 'DB Loader 2.0.' + svnversion
  return app['app_versin']
```

если ничего не ошибся, то вроде так. В уголвых скобках я специально оставил ненаписанным.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я просто думал уже писать свою структуру, а можно было просто словарем воспользоваться. Вы очень сильно меня выручили!

Comment: это неверно. К примеру, посмотрите, что [`qx//` делает](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators)

Comment: @jfs напишите аргументацию к вашему "неверно"

Comment: @norbornen: на ссылку нажмите

Comment: @jfs я знаю что там написано :)

Comment: я совсем забыл, что в питоне не сделали запуск команд через обратную кавычку.

Answer (score 0):

Возможная реализация задачи на Питоне:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import string
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE

class App:
    ...
    @property
    def version(self):
        if self.__version is None:
            p = subprocess.run(['svnversion', '-n'], stdout=PIPE, text=True)
            if p.returncode == 0 and p.stdout.startswith(tuple(string.digits)):
                svn_version = p.stdout.rstrip()
            else:  # fallback
                svn_version = '197SA'
            self.__version = f'DB Loader 2.0.{svn_version}'
        return self.__version
```